# Как убрать наложение элементов друг на друга в Android?

Tags: java, android, xml

Есть макет из трех элементов. Первая элемент это изображение, второй элемент это кастомизированный GridView, который расположен под первым элементом. И третий элемент, который всегда расположен внизу экрана. Когда экран переворачивается и gridView доходит до конца, то он слипается вместе с текстом. Как зафиксировать так, чтобы между GridView и TextView всегда было минимальное расстояние, например, 8dp.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

     <com.example.project.customViews.ExpandableHeightGridView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/gridViewNavigator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtWarning"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/gridViewNavigator"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Приложение является демонстрационным"
        android:textAlignment="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Горизонтальное расположение**
[image]

**Вертикальное расположение**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

В GridView добавить android:layout_above="@+id/txtWarning":

```
<com.example.project.customViews.ExpandableHeightGridView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/gridViewNavigator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_above="@+id/txtWarning"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="3" />
```

А у TextView указать android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtWarning"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/gridViewNavigator"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Приложение является демонстрационным"
        android:textAlignment="center" />
```